# getting custom php contact form to send email to exchange 365 account

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, contacts, contact-form

I have a website with a custom php contact form which I would like to submit the emails to an exchange 365 email address. It doesn't work and I realise it is due to microsoft 365 exchange needing authentication

I have allowed the IP in the exchange settings but to no luck

The contact form works fine for a secondary non-exchange email, i.e An email hosted on my server with POP3 settings - so I know the form is fine when not using an exchange email

I have done some research and found that perhaps it needs SMTP passwords and usernames in the contact form. I am rather new to PHP to be honest, is this the only way? it doesn't feel that safe to have the passwords etc in the code

Here is my code for the form, which works for non-exchange 365 email:

PHP:

```
<?php 
$pagetitle      =   "Contact Us";
$description    =   "";
$keywords       =   "";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/header.php");
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);
    $from = ($_POST['email']);
    $to = 'hello@mydomain.co.uk'; 
    $subject = "Enquiry from Visitor " . $name;
    $human = ($_POST['human']);

   $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


?>


<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human == '4') {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
    echo '<p>Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been sent & We will get back to you shortly!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
    } else if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>
```

Could someone please clarify if I can use this contact form to send emails to the exchange email address and if so what my options are?

I really do not want to use a 3rd party contact form like Contact Form 7 or anything like this if possible please.

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Um, you never call `mail()`...

Comment: @JohnConde doh!

Comment: sorry I do still have it further down, I will paste it here, I moved it around as read some things saying it shouldn't work with an exchange email, but I did actually put it back it was just a bit further down with the input and anti-spam code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you.

Go to https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and download it. Put it inside a directory called mail and then in the directory below use this code:

```
include("mail/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host     = "localhost";
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Username = "your-username";
$mail->Password = "your-password";              

$mail->From     = 'you@domain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Your Name';

$mail->AddAddress('recipient@domain.com'); 

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  'Subject line goes here';

$mail->Body     =  'Email body goes here';
$mail->AltBody  =  'Email body goes here';

$mail->Send();
```

Putting your SMTP authentication details in here is fine.

Next step is to go to https://www.mail-tester.com and copy the email address you see. Send an email to this address and then go back to mail-tester.com to check the result. This will tell you if you have any problems - maybe DKIM / SPF records missing. If this is the case then have a word with your host and they'll be able to help you out (or post a new question on here and somebody else can help you out)

Using PHPMailer is a much more robust way of sending emails than using PHP's mail() function.

EDIT - something like this ...

```
<?php 

    $pagetitle      =   "Contact Us";
    $description    =   "";
    $keywords       =   "";

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/header.php");
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);
    $from = ($_POST['email']);
    $to = 'hello@mydomain.co.uk'; 
    $subject = "Enquiry from Visitor " . $name;
    $human = ($_POST['human']);

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human == '4') {   

        include("mail/class.phpmailer.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host     = "localhost";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->Username    = "your-username";
        $mail->Password    = "your-password";              

        $mail->From     = $from;
        $mail->FromName = $name;

        $mail->AddAddress($to); 

        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject  =  $subject;

        $mail->Body     =  $message;
        $mail->AltBody  =  $message;

        $mail->Send();     

        echo '<p>Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been sent & We will get back to you shortly!</p>';        

    } elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is PHP mailer a whole new form or just the php part of it? excuse my stupidity I am rather new.. I really do not want to change the actual input part of the form as I have spent a while styling it etc, is there anyway I can just add the SMTP settings to my current mail() function contact form? Thanks for your help and suggestion :)

Comment: Exactly. Your HTML remains exactly as it is. Just get rid of your $headers line and then replace your call to mail() with my block of code. Give it a go, it's easier than you think.

Comment: Thank you :) I will give it a go, will it affect my anti-spam question? i.e do I need to change any input?

Comment: No, that can all be kept.

Comment: But I have to download and add some files to my website is that correct? I cannot just swap the php for the php code above? Sorry I am not great at php just yet..

Comment: ah yes I have just realised what this is! I am not sure I will do it correctly but I will try, I haven't used additional things like this before

Comment: Just to clarify, if there anyway of just adding the smpt settings to my current php form or will I be wasting my time?

Comment: Thank you, I was just reading instructions on github and it is implying I need to install composer etc for this to work, it is just a standard bootstrap frameworks website I do not have composer, am I being stupid?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. Just click "Clone or Download" and then choose to download the zip.

Comment: I have done this but am getting 
Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/trsecuradmin/public_html/mail/class.phpmailer.php on line 1520

Comment: Did you upload everything from the zip into your mail directory? Seems like you didn't

Comment: everything, unzipped in mail folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138987/discussion-between-chris-and-ck777).

Comment: is there anyway of just adding smpt settings to my current form? I have never used anything like this before and it is not working so i must be doing something wrong